# RTCIceCandidate instance cannot be created in browsers on moblie devices

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webrtc

I'm recently trying some awesome features of HTML5 and WebRTC, and am building a site to allow multiple people video chat.

Everything works just fine on my PC and the Media Capture of HTML5 works like a charm. But when I set up a video source on my PC, and try to connect to it via my android/iphone/ipad, it just did not work. I checked the logs, it suggests that the creation of RTCIceCandidate failed for some unknown reason:

```
// To be processed as either Client or Server
case "CANDIDATE":
    trace("************important*********", "we get in");
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({candidate: msg.candidate});
    trace("************important*********", JSON.stringify(candidate));
break;
```

turns out the second log never shows up.

Anyone has any idea? Is is because such features are not available on mobile devices for now? Or should I do something specially for mobile devices?

oh and this is the callback of IceCandidatem which is never called:

```
// This function sends candidates to the remote peer, via the node server
var onIceCandidate = function(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {

       trace("openChannel","Sending ICE candidate to remote peer : " +  event.candidate.candidate);
       var msgCANDIDATE = {};
       msgCANDIDATE.msg_type  = 'CANDIDATE';
       msgCANDIDATE.candidate = event.candidate.candidate;
       msgCANDIDATE.peer = server;
       msgCANDIDATE.me = weAreActingAs;
       //trace("openChannel","candidate peer : " + JSON.stringify(event));
       socket.send(JSON.stringify(msgCANDIDATE));

    } else {
       trace("onIceCandidate","End of candidates");
    }
}
```

The server is in nodejs.

Thanks so much guys! Need your hands!

Comment: Not sure if this could be related to your device settings. Does the following site work on your device?(it didn't on mine but I've got an old android phone): http://www.simpl.info/getusermedia/

Comment: Nah, @HMR, I either cannot get it to work on my Nexus 4, android 4.2.2, chrome 25.0 nor safari on ip5, so I guess it's just that such features are not supported on mobile devices now? I'd be really sad if that's the case :(

Comment: I'm no expert on webrtc but according to the following site there should be supported for IOS and Android: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/WebRTC-hits-Firefox-Android-and-iOS but you'll need to use the ericsson browser

Comment: In one of the comments it does say that ericsson browser uses the depreciated ROAP signaling and can't be used in peer communication with (for example) Chrome. One comment states that blackbarry native browser now supports getUserMedia so maybe Android and iOS will follow. No native support at the moment though. And ericsson browser implementation seems to be based on depreciated standards.

Comment: @HMR thanks a lot for the info, man. Then I guess this have to wait now. Please paste your comments to answer the question so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to test device support here: http://www.simpl.info/getusermedia/

I'm no expert on webrtc but according to the following site there should be supported for IOS and Android: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/WebRTC-hits-Firefox-Android-and-iOS but you'll need to use the ericsson browser

In one of the comments it does say that ericsson browser uses the depreciated ROAP signaling and can't be used in peer communication with (for example) Chrome. One comment states that blackbarry native browser now supports getUserMedia so maybe Android and iOS will follow. No native support at the moment though. And ericsson browser implementation seems to be based on depreciated standards.